# Embedding a graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with partial geometric information

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

I have a connected, sparse, graph (a molecule to be specific) and I'm interested in associating 3D coordinates with the vertices. Here's the kicker: I already have coordinates for none/some/all vertices which are not to be changed. The case of no coordinates I can solve with e.g. MDS, and the case where I have all coordinates is trivial.

In addition, I have a length associated with every edge which should be respected (but some distortion is fine). If it helps, I also have information about some (not all) angles and dihedral angles. Finally, all vertices should be separated as much as possible from one another.
If need be, you may assume a maximum degree of ~6.

I don't expect a fully worked solution, but any pointers to literature would already be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe write down the energy function and perform simulated annealing?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll give that a try. Although it feels somewhat unsatisfactory ;)

Comment: There're lots of optimization algorithms to try, not only limited to simulated annealing.

Comment: Don't worry, I realize. The first thing I'll try will be some local optimization, preferably one I can take from scipy. But that's more StackOverflow than MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of papers by Mike Treacy (I. Rivin is a co-author on some) which address this problem, but in a purely practical manner, using essentially the scheme proposed by Bullet51. Here is one:

```
Enumeration of periodic tetrahedral frameworks
M Treacy, KH Randall, S Rao, JA Perry, DJ Chadi
Zeitschrift fur Kristallographie 212 (11), 768-791
```